# Parse.com how to separate objects based on createdAt day?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I've been looking to query for all of the "posts" a user has made, which I've done, and then separate them into sections in a UICollectionViewCell based on their createdAt day. So that my collection view headers will have the day and the under there will be to posts made that day. Perhaps I'm overthinking this too much? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not overthinking, sounds fine, but it isn't a question. How did you try to do it and what went wrong?

Comment: Only thing I tried  was creating an array that holds arrays of the posts belonging to a single day. This would work, although i couldn't figure out how to  tell when the day changes when i loop through the posts. I guess that would make a better question

Answer (score 0):

[This answer provides a way to get the start and end dates for the current day.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34034093/4080860)

You'll then have to figure out how to sort the objects, but I'll leave that up to you.

Separating a lot of objects out into sections with `NSDate` comparisions may or may not affect your app's performance, so you'll have to be wary of that, but don't worry about it if you don't notice anything.