# Parse check if object was created today? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to write a `PFQuery` for my application that returns only objects that were created today. With all the depreciations that happened to `NSDate` and the growing importance of `NSDateFormatter` I am finding rather hard to go about this.

I have figured the logic to be like this in pseudo-code:

```
Query q = new Query();
q.whereDateGreaterThan(midnightThisMorning);
q.whereDateLessThan(midnightTonight);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get a `NSDate` object set to 12:00 AM (which would be `midnightThisMorning`) and another set to 11:59 PM tonight (which would be `midnightTonight`).

Comment: There is a pod called MTDate that can make your life much easier comparing dates, as it handles the NSDateFormatter as an singleton u don't need to worry about the performance.

Comment: sudo-code would be super privilege code, you mean pseudo-code :)

Comment: Don't use a formatter, use a calendar and date components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `NSCalendar`'s `startOfDayForDate` method to find the start of the current day.

To find the end of the current day, you'll want to add a day to the date returned from `startOfDayForDate` and then subtract one second.